# vuejs-laravel js not working after component switching

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a JS script declared on my laravel view, below the app.js containing all the vuejs components.
In this script I have elements like charts or a script allowing me to change the monthly price to annual.

And when I switch component, the js doesn't load, while when I refresh the page, it works.

There's probably an option I don't know, which would avoid that?

Thank you in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Skrap-it</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicons/favicon.ico"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/icons.css') }}">

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/dashboard/scripts.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

My router js file

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import Register from '../components/auth/Register'
import Login from '../components/auth/Login'
import Profile from '../components/dashboard/Profile'
import Apis from '../components/dashboard/Apis'
import Packages from '../components/dashboard/Packages'
import Support from '../components/dashboard/Support'
import Admin from '../components/dashboard/Admin'
import Dashboard from '../components/dashboard/Dashboard'

const routes = [
    { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard },
    { path: '/login', component: Login },
    { path: '/register', component: Register },
    { path: '/profile', component: Profile },
    { path: '/packages', component: Packages },
    { path: '/support', component: Support },
    { path: '/admin', component: Admin },
    { path: '/apis', component: Apis },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    hashbang: false,
})

export default router
```

My app.js file

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './Router/router'

import '../../public/css/dashboard/main.css';
import '../../public/css/custom.css';

window.Vue = require('vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

And I switch to another component with router link to="my_component"

Comment: Please provide your actual code so we can see what you've done. Also provide information on how you bundle your javascript - do you use laravel mix? plain webpack? or simply nothing but pure scripts between <script> tags?

Comment: @FrankProvost Yes I use Laravel Mix, just to combine multiple files to 1 file, and there is my laravel view : `<body>
<div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/dashboard/scripts.js') }}"></script>

</body> `

Comment: You should edit your question and add this code :)

Comment: Ok, sorry i'm not ok with SOF haha

Comment: no worries - I'll edit the question for your, you've actually added an answer :) - could you please also check what your developer console says when the error occurs? If you are using chrome press F12 and go to console in the bottom right corner. And by switchting components you probably mean changing the vue-component via the vue-router right?

Comment: Please also add what your javascript coding to the question

Comment: No errors, the switch doesn't engage anything, the prices don't change, and the graphs don't appear.

Comment: It's a bunch of heavy libs, I don't know if I can post it here.

Comment: I'll try to see if it's a VueJS issue, that the scripts are not loading, or a problem coming from my javascript libraries.
I'll create a simple file that consoles .log something.

Comment: You should not post the libs content - only what you've implemented. How do you integrate the libs, how is your routing setup, how do you navigate to "switch a component" - only show what is relevant for the issue

Comment: I try with simple function to print console.log when I checked the checkbox, and it works, I think the problem come from my js libs

Comment: It also makes me think that I did the front end without using VueJS, and that I could do all this very simply with VueJS from the components directly ...
Well in the end the problem is not coming from VueJS as I thought, but from my own code, I wanted to go a bit too fast on SOF this time...